# Where app drops sdk version info

Tags: android-versions, facebook-messenger, sdk

Long story short i used appcloner to spoof android SDK version to lower to get messenger chat heads as they were on android 10 and lower. I copied the installed app, so now i got .apk with all that info and when i install it from that file it still works. App must dropped info about android SDK into it's files, but i cannot find where. Does anyone could help me with that?

My goal is to inject this file into original messenger apk so that i could update this app from official messenger .apk

Comment: Hi, it seems you're accidentally creating a new account. Please refer to [how to merge your accounts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can regain ownership of the question and post comments on any post under your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If an app behaves differently on a higher or lower Android version, then it uses code like that (before the app has been compiled):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    // do something on Android 6+
} else {
    // do something on Android before version 6
}
```

Such code structures will be present in multiple classes of the app. If you want to forge the Android version in the original app you have to decompile the APK using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) modify every occurrence of such a structure e.g. by replacing the access to `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` which queries the device's Android ADK version and replace it by a constant like `29` for Android 10 and the rebuild the APK using apktool, `zipalign` and sign (`apksigner`) it and then you are ready to install the app.

Unfortunately apktool does only generate Smali code and not Java code, which makes the whole task much more difficult as Smali is very low level and not easy to read.

There may be existing programs/apps that already do such modifications in an automated way, unfortunately I don't know or use such apps.

Comment: Thing is that I managed to fool app thinking that it runs on Android 10, and copying whole installed app to another device works as well, so this info should be somewhere in files that it runs on Android 10. The goal is to copy this file and inject it into stock messenger app

Comment: @Kamkol You wrote you used appcloner (whatever that is you forgot to provide a link in your question) for that. If the app does not actually clone the app but just runs the app in a different context it is possible to forge the runtime information in memory. As I wrote the info of the current Android version is not in the app but in the process itself at run-time.